# CSS to Display Post Grid in One Column Like the Image I added

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is an example of the grid I need :   [1](https://trendzcity.com.ng/): https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyOuz.png

i want to Display Post Grid in One Column in my mobile theme instead of the 2x2 grid. Every of the box will be aligned in one column. full width but reduction in height.

here is another example [View on mobile phone](https://trendzcity.com.ng/)

Here is my HTML & CSS

```css
  *{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    html{
      background-color:#eee;
    }
    .container{
      margin: 20px auto;
      width:400px;
      height:400px;
      background-color:#fff;
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
      grid-row: auto auto;
      grid-column-gap: 20px;
      grid-row-gap: 20px;
      .box{
        background-color:#333;
        padding:20px;
        border-radius:10px;
        color:#fff;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center;
        font-size:40px;
        font-family:sans-serif;
      }

    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">A</div>
      <div class="box">B</div>
      <div class="box">C</div>
      <div class="box">D</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You use css pre-processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not want to use mediaqueries, you may use `auto-fill` and `minmax()` to set your columns width, you also need to allow the container to shrink width `max-width`:

Snippet that you can play in fullpage to check behavior on resize.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.container {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 100%;/* NEW */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, 1fr)); /* UPDATE */
  grid-row: auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using [CSS @media rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media). Using these it is possible to set specific CSS properties based on screen width for example.

Using your provided example above, we can add a `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {}` rule to mean that any screens LESS than or EQUAL TO 600px in width will use this style instead.

```css
   * {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      box-sizing:border-box;
}
   
html {
      background-color:#eee;
}

.container{
      margin: 20px auto;
      width:400px;
      height:400px;
      background-color:#fff;
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
      grid-row: auto auto;
      grid-column-gap: 20px;
      grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.box{
      background-color:#333;
      padding:20px;
      border-radius:10px;
      color:#fff;
      display:flex;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:center;
      font-size:40px;
      font-family:sans-serif;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .container {
         display:grid;
         grid-template-columns: 200px;
         grid-row: auto;
         grid-column-gap: 20px;
         grid-row-gap: 20px;
     }
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">A</div>
      <div class="box">B</div>
      <div class="box">C</div>
      <div class="box">D</div>
    </div>
```